# How to draw lines between points and save as array of coordinates IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, image-processing, drawing, ionic4

I'm creating a new app in ionic for a hobby and I'm getting big dudes.
I want to create a page to draw points over an image and save this points into an array of coordinates.

For example:

[image]
Upload an image

[image]
Set the position of the dots in relation to the image as array for example: ["75,85", "82,35", "76,15", "70,35", "22,07"]

[image]
Draw line between point posisiton

The dude is how to draw dots over the image and store their position in an array like  ["75,85", "82,35", "76,15", "70,35", "22,07"].

Can I use any library for this?

Is simple or difficult task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be looking into using the `<canvas>` tag if I was trying to build this from scratch.

The first task is to figure out out how to draw lines to your satisfaction. For example, there is a built in `lineTo()` function as part of the canvas api:

```
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
```

I just grabbed this from [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_stroke.asp).

To do this the Ionic way though you would need to get the native element using [perhaps this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-canvas-drawing-files/).

That tutorial shows how to do both getting the canvas in Ionic and drawing lines.

Add a canvas tag like this:

```
<canvas #imageCanvas></canvas>
```

Get it from the code by using a viewchild like this:

```
@ViewChild('imageCanvas') canvas: any;
```

And then read its nativeElement like this:

```
this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
```

After that you can use the `lineTo` code from above. In fact, if you read that tutorial it uses the same technique to draw lots of little lines to look like a mouse drawing mode.

And if you position the image using css absolute positioning above the canvas it will work as a background image, I think by default, but I'm pretty sure you can make the canvas bg transparent.

Comment: Than you @rtpHarry for your help, I will read more about canvas in ionic and I will try developing it.